# How to fix Remote name could not be resolved in C# HTTP Request;

Tags: c#, wpf, https, dns

I recently switched my backend-server to https and going into production I deployed it on a AWS EC2, but my windows-client refuses to communicate with the server, and gives me an exception with the message:

> "Remote name could not be resolved"

Here's a sample code

```
public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificatecertification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://api.mybackend.com/login");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(User.Login());

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    if (responseString != null)
    {
        return GrailsController.Instance.User.Parse(responseString);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

The exception occurs on `var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();` and for the love of god I can't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: If this is the sample of your URL: `api.mybackend.com/login` shouldn't it be `https://api.mybackend.com/login`? Can you try and get some get requests working through a browser?

Comment: I forgot to write the protocol in the sample, I'll add it now. Requests are indeed working with Postman

Comment: It's a DNS issue for sure if its unable resolve the remote hostname. If you do a lookup from the same machine does it resolve correctly?

Comment: The thing is that I have a nginx.conf on my server which forwards requests sent to `api.mybackend.com` to `project-api.mybackend.com` and in the message it says that `project-api` could not be resolved, even though the client should not be able to realize that this happens

Comment: @kesslkaserer I'm pretty sure that's how a CNAME works. The DNS response for `api.mybackend.com` will be presented with `project-api.mybackend.com` and another query on the alias will be needed (which happens automatically) to grab the A record. Can your server/client resolve `project-api.mybackend.com`?